# Using InsertMany with ArrayList<Object> in mongoDB with springboot

Tags: java, json, mongodb, insert, spring-data

Is it possible to use insertMany for an ArrayList?
I implemented a code but the data didn't insert into the collection.

```
ObjectId logId = new ObjectId();
    LogFile data =logfileRepo.save(new LogFile(String.valueOf(logId), fileName, now));
   
    ArrayList<Object> listdata = new ArrayList<>();
    if (arr != null) {

        //Iterating JSON array
        for (int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){

            //Adding each element of JSON array into ArrayList
            listdata.add(arr.get(i));
        }
    }
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new 
    MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://rusiru:rus@cluster0.xemlu.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority"));
    MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("LApp");
    database.createCollection(String.valueOf(logId));
    database.getCollection(String.valueOf(logId)).insertMany(listdata)
```

here `arr`is a jsonArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to map those objects to MongoDB Documents.

> void insertMany(java.util.List<? **extends TDocument**> documents)

Use a library that will do the mapping for you, like [Morphia](https://www.baeldung.com/mongodb-morphia), or you can do like this:

```
ObjectId logId = new ObjectId();
LogFile data =logfileRepo.save(new LogFile(String.valueOf(logId), fileName, now));
List<Document> documents = arr.stream()
            .map(jsonStr -> Document.parse(jsonStr))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new 
MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://rusiru:rus@cluster0.xemlu.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority"));
MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("LApp");
database.createCollection(String.valueOf(logId));
database.getCollection(String.valueOf(logId)).insertMany(documents);
```

Comment: I didn't get the point can you bit explain, please

Comment: Sure. The method you are calling is expecting a certain Object type as argument - List of MongoDB Document. Does it compile for you with ArrayList<Object>?

Comment: No, it doesn't compile, I wanted to insert the JsonArray into the MongoDB collection. For that, I converted the jsonArray into ArrayList.

Comment: Right, so you can call the method with ArrayList<Document>. If you already have a JSON, you can create a Document like this: Document.parse(jsonStr);

Comment: @Riyana I have edited my answer, so it will be more straightforward, let me know if it doesn't help

Comment: There is an error at parse.// Reference to 'parse' is ambiguous, both 'parse(String)' and 'parse(String, Decoder<Document>)' match

Comment: Fixed it. Is it OK now?

Comment: Sorry to bother you. Now it gives an error like this. // 'parse(java.lang.String)' in 'org.bson.Document' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.Object)'

Comment: Sure, great job